# Removing '\n' from a string without using .translate, .replace or strip()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, class

I'm making a simple text-based game as a learning project. I'm trying to add a feature where the user can input 'save' and their stats will be written onto a txt file named 'save.txt' so that after the program has been stopped, the player can then upload their previous stats and play from where they left off.

Here is the code for the saving:

user inputs 'save' and class attributes are saved onto the text file as text, one line at a time

```
elif first_step == 'save':
    f = open("save.txt", "w")
    f.write(f'''{player1.name}
    {player1.char_type} #value is 'Wizard'
    {player1.life} 
    {player1.energy}
    {player1.strength}
    {player1.money}
    {player1.weapon_lvl}
    {player1.wakefulness}
    {player1.days_left}
    {player1.battle_count}''')
    f.close()
```

But, I also need the user to be able to load their saved stats next time they run the game. So they would enter 'load' and their stats will be updated.

I'm trying to read the text file one line at a time and then the value of that line would become the value of the relevant class attribute in order, one at a time. If I do this without converting it first to a string I get issues, such as some lines being skipped as python is reading 2 lines as one and putting them altogether as a list.

So, I tried the following:

In the below example, I'm only showing the data from the class attributes 'player1.name' and 'player1.char_type' as seen above as to not make this question as short as possible.

```
elif first_step == 'load':
    f = open("save.txt", 'r')        
    player1.name_saved = f.readline() #reads the first line of the text file and assigns it's value to player1.name_saved
    player1.name_saved2 = str(player1.name_saved)  # converts the value of player1.name_saved to a string and saves that string in player1.name_saved2
    player1.name = player1.name_saved2 #assigns the value of player1.name_saved to the class attribute player1.name

    player1.char_type_saved = f.readlines(1) #reads the second line of the txt file and saves it in player1.char_type_saved
    player1.char_type_saved2 = str(player1.char_type_saved) #converts the value of player1.char_type_saved into a string and assigns that value to player1.char_type_saved2
```

At this point, I would assign the value of player1.char_type_saved2 to the class attribute player1.char_type so that the value of player1.char_type enables the player to load the previous character type from the last time they played the game. This should make the value of player1.char_type = 'Wizard' but I'm getting '['Wizard\n']'

I tried the following to remove the brackets and \n:

```
final_player1.char_type = player1.char_type_saved2.translate({ord(c): None for c in "[']\n" }) #this is intended to remove everything from the string except for Wizard
```

For some reason, the above only removes the square brackets and punctuation marks but not \n from the end.

I then tried the following to remove \n:

```
final_player1.char_type = final_player1.char_type.replace("\n", "")
```

final_player1.char_type is still 'Wizard\n'

I've also tried using strip() but I've been unsuccessful.

If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it. Sorry if I have overcomplicated this question but it's hard to articulate it without lots of info. Let me know if this is too much or if more info is needed to answer.

Comment: `f.readline()` returns a string. There is no need to call `str`.

Comment: `strip()` should work. `player1.name_saved = f.readline().strip()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "but it's hard to articulate it without lots of info" Only because you are not accustomed to *trying to narrow down the problem*. For example, can you cause the problem with a `Player` class with fewer attributes in it? Does the problem occur for all attributes, or only some of them? If it only occurs for some of them, can you see a difference between how they are handled?

Comment: I suggest you use JSON or Pickle to save data, instead of reading and writing the text file in your own code.

Comment: Hint: what does the code say beside the comment `#reads the first line of the text file and assigns it's value to player1.name_saved`? What does the code say beside the comment `#reads the second line of the txt file and saves it in player1.char_type_saved`? Are those two lines of code using the same approach to read the file? Is there a reason they should use different approaches? Hint: what happens when you do `str(['\n'])`? How many characters are in the resulting string, and what are they?

Comment: "I tried the following to remove the brackets and \n:" Instead of trying to figure out how to remove them, why not first try to figure out *why they are there*? After all, you didn't *expect* them, right? You didn't consciously put any brackets into your file data, right? So that should *surprise* you and *get your attention* and be something you want to *think* about. That's what programmers do.

Comment: "For some reason, the above only removes the square brackets and punctuation marks but not \n from the end." That is because `"[']\n"` contains a newline, but your actual string contains an actual backslash and lowercase n instead.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel - They are using slightly different approaches because when I use readline for both of them I get the full line for player1.name_saved and only the first character for player1.char_type_saved. And I can't have the program read a certain amount of characters because it could be different depending on the values.  Also, because when I print player1.char_type_saved I get ['Wizard\n'] but when I print player1.name_saved I just get 'name' without any square brackets, punctuation marks and \n. I've also tried many approaches. I know I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel It did surprise me when I saw this, that's why I'm trying to convert them and remove those characters, this isn't my first approach to the problem

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Also, if I don't first convert player1.char_type_saved to a string, I get the following error when printing it 'player1.char_type_saved = player1.char_type_saved.translate({ ord(c): None for c in "[']\n" }' - This lead me to believe it was a list and needed to be converted and I also don't get this error after I convert it to a string, but the \n is still there, thanks for your answers btw

Comment: "They are using slightly different approaches because when I use readline for both of them I get the full line for player1.name_saved and only the first character for player1.char_type_saved. " No, it will definitely *read* a complete *line* of your file. Something else must have happened on that other attempt at the code.

Comment: "I get the following error" *That isn't an error*; that's just the *part of* the error message telling you where in the code the error happened. "This lead me to believe it was a list" It was. "and needed to be converted" No. If something is not what you should be, and also *different from what you intended*, your first thought should not be "how can I force this thing to play nice?" It should be "why did I not get the result I wanted? How can I fix the previous code so that I get the result I want, instead?"

Comment: The nature of the list (and converted string) that you're getting *proves* that you just need to use `.readline` in the exact same way that you used for `player1.name_saved`. If you don't believe me, try changing that one to use other approach, and watch as it not only stops working, but breaks *in the same way*.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel - This works for the 2 examples I gave but it gets much worse when I use this with integers or floats - I think I just need to go back to the drawing board and better understand what my code is actually doing. Thanks for the advice, this has helped

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks, I think that's probably a better approach than the way I'm currently trying to do it

Comment: "but it gets much worse when I use this with integers or floats" Just read a line of text in the same way, and convert it to the appropriate type. After all, each value is on a separate line in the file, right? That's what your output template looks like to me, anyway.

Comment: "I've also tried using strip() but I've been unsuccessful." Try using it on a string that you get by using `f.readline()`.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel - So, the value of player1.life is 89 in this example. 

I used the following player_life = f.readlines(2) - if I print that I get ['89\n']
If I try player_life = player_life.replace("\n", "") - I get the following: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
So, I convert it to a string and try the same thing but I still get ['89\n']

Comment: @Karl Knechtel
Then, I tried player_life = player_life.translate({ ord(c): None for c in "[']\n" })

And I get 89\n

I again try player_life = player_life.replace("\n", "") 

And I still get 89\n

If i try readline instead of readlines I only get the first character, and I can't enter how many characters it will be as it could be different depending on the stats of the previous session

Comment: @Karl Knechtel - Also, strip did work when I used it on the examples here but not when I try to do it with player1.life it removes most of the characters from player1.char_type

Comment: You need to do more analysis, focus the question and ask again from the beginning, following all the previous advice.

Answer (score 0):

If `'\n'` is always at the end it may be best to use:

```
s = 'wizard\n'
s = s[:-1]
print(s, s)
```

Output:

```
wizard wizard
```

But I still think `strip()` is best:

```
s = 'wizard\n'
s = s.strip()
print(s, s)
```

Output:

```
wizard wizard
```

Answer (score 0):

Normaly it should work with just

```
char_type = "Wizard\n"
char_type.replace("\n", "")
print(char_type)
```

The output will be "Wizard"